# weighted.median no longer existed in latested released versions of spatstat

Tags: spatstat

#### Scenario:

I realized than in `v1.63-2` of `spatstat` package, function `weighted.mean()` no longer exist (but exist in `v1.56-1`).

#### Question:

Is there a certain reason leading to the removal of this function or if it's been renamed?

Comment: Welcome to SO! However, that is a question best asked of the package maintainer. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what it's all about.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about `weighted.mean` or `weighted.median`? (Your question header mentions `weighted.median` but the  question body mentions `weighted.mean`)

There is no function `weighted.mean` in the `spatstat` package (not in the current version and not in any previous version). The function `weighted.mean` is a generic function in the base R system (in the recommended package `stats`) which has several methods such as `weighted.mean.default`. There are also no methods for `weighted.mean` in the `spatstat` package (not in the current version and not in any previous version).

There *is* a function `weighted.median` in the `spatstat` package. It was introduced in `spatstat` version 1.47-0 and has been present in all subsequent versions.